# PHP regex on string

Tags: php, regex

I have this little code to extract the `#hashtags`:

```
$text = 'The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. #lorem #ipsum #another#tags';
$content  = explode(' ', $text);
$tags = array();
foreach ($content as $item){
    if (preg_match('/#([^\s]+)/', $item, $matches)) {
        $tags[]= $matches[0];
    }
}
```

And got this:

```
Array(
    [0] => #lorem
    [1] => #ipsum
    [2] => #another#tags
)
```

The question is: How I can match even the `#another#tags` and append to my current array?

New trouble: some text has urls like *http://someurl.com/here.html#top* and the `#top` part is parsed like a tag too. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Do you mean you want four tags: #lorem, #ipsum, #another, and #tags?

Comment: Twitter hashtags cannot have a # in the middle. In fact, they can only have `[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]*`. Updating your regex should fix the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is just pull out all of the hash tags, then you can simply do this:

```
$text = 'The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. #lorem #ipsum #another#tags';
preg_match_all("/\#\\w+/", $text, $matches);
$tags = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Adding a look behind such as: (?<!http[^\s]*) before the # should work, but there seems to be a bug in some php versions that doesn't allow this. You could always just check the array for elements that begin with "http://" and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Regex1 `/#([^(\s#)]+)/`

Regex2 `/#([^\s^#)]+)/`